# FFMPEG with AVFoundation on MacOS 12.3.1 - USB capture device not recorded at full framerate

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video

I have been trying to get my USB capture device working with FFMPEG 6.0 so that I can have a little more flexibility than OBS offers. I have been running in to some issues with the framerate at any resolution, and even when copying the raw video stream. I do not believe this to be a problem with my capture card, because OBS records from the device at full 60 FPS at 1920x1080.

Here is my full FFMPEG command:

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 60.000240 -rtbufsize 100M -video_size 1920x1080 -i "1:" -c:v libx264 output.mkv`

What I have tried:

Specifying framerate with `-framerate 60` and `-framerate 60.000240`

Using a lower resolution incase this is a bandwidth issue

Copying raw video stream incase this is an issue of my CPU simply not encoding fast enough

My current theory is that perhaps my USB capture device has a switchable output (I have heard that some capture devices can output raw video or MJPEG and switch between the 2) but 1 of the outputs is low framerate.

Below is a list of the resolutions and framerates that FFMPEG believes are suitable for my device.

```
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   640x480@[5.000000 30.000030]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   640x480@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   720x480@[5.000000 30.000030]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   720x480@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   720x576@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   720x576@[5.000000 25.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   800x600@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   800x600@[5.000000 20.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1024x768@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1024x768@[10.000000 10.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1280x720@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1280x720@[10.000000 10.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1280x960@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1280x960@[8.000000 8.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1280x1024@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1280x1024@[8.000000 8.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1360x768@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1360x768@[8.000000 8.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1600x1200@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1600x1200@[5.000000 5.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1920x1080@[10.000000 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x1470040c0]   1920x1080@[5.000000 5.000000]fps
```

Comment: In case you like to check MJPEG format, try adding `-input_format mjpeg` (before the `-i`). I don't know if the feature is supported with avfoundation.